# How can I use h:graphicImage to show a URL in a tab

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am writing a small application where I take a search string and show the results in the **tabs** with different search servers like Google,Yahoo,Bing etc., on the onkeyup event of the searchString inputText. I have tried to use h:graphicImage as well as h:outputLink with no results. h:graphicImage, I think, is expecting a relative path not absolute path and h:outputLink is working just like the anchor tag. Is there any other way to get what I am expecting it to do?

```
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="panelGroupClass">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:graphicImage value = "#{searchController.googleURL}" alt="Google URL"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:graphicImage>` expects an URL to an **image** (a file with `.jpg`, `.gif`, `.png` or whatever extension) and will show it in a HTML `<img>` element. If the URL is relative (i.e. it doesn't start with `http://` then it's relative to the domain where *your* website runs. If it is absolute (i.e. it starts with `http://`), then, well, it's absolute :)

---

**Update** as per the comments, you seem to want to embed the complete HTML output of an external site in your webpage. You should basically be using a HTML `<iframe>` for this.

```
<iframe src="#{searchController.googleURL}"></iframe>
```

There are no standard JSF components which renders a HTML `<iframe>` element. Above should however just work as good when you're using Facelets instead of JSP.

Comment: Well, actually the way I asked my question itself might be wrong(Caffeine blurs my mind). I am trying to do something like the Google Chrome tabs except that my tabs should dynamically change their appearance depending upon the string I enter. That could be done using Ajax, but the initial problem I have is to show the pages in tabs and I couldn't get an idea on how to do that.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need a `<h:graphicImage>`. Do you want a HTML `<img>` element? What exactly do those URLs represent?

Comment: I am sorry that I am confusing you this bad. I will start from scratch. I am trying to show some webpages in tabs with the search string I attach in the inputText. To do that I have tried using <h:graphicImage> thinking it would work. However I am wrong as this tag can only render images not webpages. I have to find another way to show the webpages in tabs. The whole reason to show webpages in tabs is to present more data to the user in the initial screen. I am not sure if you understand this, if you didn't understand this we can let go of the whole issue.

Comment: Oh, how did I forget about <iframe>, thanks much. That really helps.